# Counts of a full outer left join and an inner join don't add up to count(*) of a table

Tags: sql

I've written a basic left outer join on table Mouse to table Pad. To make sure that I was getting the right set and quantity of data, I ran an inner join of Mouse and Pad and added the inner join's count(star) to the left outer join's count(star) which is greater than the count(*) of table Mouse by 12.

Here's the left outer join:

```
select *
from mouse.crm_mmbi_contacts mouse
left outer join pad.lean_contact pad
on mouse.email_address = pad.email_addr
where pad.email_addr IS NULL
order by email_address
```

And here's the inner join:

```
select *
from mouse.crm_mmbi_contacts mouse
inner join pad.lean_contact pad
on mouse.email_address = pad.email_addr
order by email_address
```

I ran the left outer join without the `where` clause and the result set was basically the entire table itself, plus the extra 12 rows... Also, there is only 1 row where the email_address is NULL.

What should I look to filter or edit?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting more results from your `Left Join` than you have in your `Mouse` table, then it suggests that your `pad` table has a many:1 relationship to your `mouse` table. If you are expecting 1:1 then check for duplicate `email_Addr` in your `pad` table.

You also mention that you are seeing less records in your `inner join` query than in your `left join` query. This suggests that you lack `email_addr` values in your `pad` table that exist in your `mouse` table. If you are expecting a `mouse LEFT JOIN pad` to return the same number of records as `mouse INNER JOIN pad` then insure that every `email_address` in `mouse` exists in `pad`.

For example:

`mouse.email_address` has the following values: 1,2,3,4,5,7

and

`pad.email_addr` has the following values: 1,2,2,4,6,6

Then `SELECT mouse.email_address FROM mouse LEFT JOIN pad on email_address = email_addr` will yield: 1,2,2,3,4,5,7 (a count of 7 rows)

`Select mouse.email_Address from mouse INNER JOIN pad on email_address = email_Addr` will yield: 1,2,2,4 (a count of 4 records)

Comment: You're right in your first paragraph about the relationship between the 2 tables. However, there's nothing I can do about the `pad` table having duplicate entries. I checked for duplicates in the `pad` table, and there are a lot. A lot more than the difference of 12 I saw in the counts. As to the 2nd paragraph, I wasn't very clear in my original description. So I'm not expecting the `inner join` to output the same # of records as the `left join`. I'm actually expecting the 2 joins to add together to be equal to the count(*) of `mouse`

Comment: Your `left join` without the `WHERE` statement should be exactly as many records as are in `Mouse`. That's the nature of the `Left Join`. Furthermore, if you have duplicate `email_addr` in your pads table then the total in your `left join` will be the number of records in your `mouse` table plus the number of duplicates in your `pad` table where the duplicate contains an `email_addr` that is also in `mouse`. If the duplicate in `pad` doesn't have a matching `email_address` in mouse then it won't come through in your `left join` possibly explaining why you only get 12 extra records.

Comment: Are you sure the last sentence in your comment is correct? Because, wouldn't it be the other way around? As in, if the duplicate in `mouse` doesn't have a matching `email_address` in `pad` then it won't come through in the `left join` explaining why I only get 12 extra records

Comment: Your `left join` is written as `SELECT * FROM mouse LEFT JOIN pad on mouse.email_Address = pad.email_addr` This is saying to select all records from `Mouse` and only the records from `pad` where pad's email_addr is also in `mouse`. So.. if there is an email in `mouse` that isn't in `pad` it will still be in the results. If there is an email address in `pad` that isn't in `mouse` then the record will still come through, but `pad.email_addr` will be null. If there are two records in `pad` that are also in `mouse` then there will be two records returned, one for each match in `pad`

Comment: Okay, so the problem I'm having is that records in the intersection of `mouse` and `pad` are still showing up in the `left join` for some reason. I went through and noticed that the 12 extra records are all in the intersection and have duplicates. This is all happening with the `where` clause back in the `left outer join`

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use your `where pad.email_addr is null` clause in your `left join` statement, you are still getting 12 extra records?

Comment: Yep, that's where I'm getting the 12 extra records